# SharedPerference key returning null value in Flutter

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences

I created a `user model` where I'm saving required data to save in `sharedperference` so that if user kill the app so I can get it from `sharedperference`. here is my user model looks like.

```
class UserModel {
  String? token;
  String? userId;
  String? stripeId;
  String? userName;
  String? userEmailAddress;
 
  UserModel({this.activeCardId,this.token,this.userId,this.stripeId,this.userName});

  UserModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    token = json['token'];
    userId = json['user_id'];
    stripeId = json['stripe_id'];
    userName=json['fullname'];
    userEmailAddress=json['email'];

  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data =  <String, dynamic>{};
    data['token'] = token;
    data['user_id'] = userId;
    data['stripe_id'] = stripeId;
    data['fullname']=userName;
    data['email']=userEmailAddress;
    return data;
  }
}
```

and here is my `sharedperference` class code, i used `provider` state management for this

```
class UserViewModel with ChangeNotifier{

  Future<bool> saveUser(UserModel user)async{

    final SharedPreferences sp = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    sp.setString('token', user.token.toString());
    sp.setString('user_id',user.userId.toString());
    sp.setString('stripe_id',user.stripeId.toString());
    sp.setString('userName',user.userName.toString());
    sp.setString('userEmailAddress',user.userEmailAddress.toString());
    notifyListeners();
    return true ;
  }

  Future<UserModel> getUser()async{

    final SharedPreferences sp = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final String? token = sp.getString('token');
    final String? userId = sp.getString('user_id');
    final String? stripeId=sp.getString('stripe_id');
    final String? userName=sp.getString('userName');
    final String? userEmailAddress=sp.getString('userEmailAddress');

    return UserModel(
      token: token.toString(),
      userId: userId.toString(),
      stripeId: stripeId.toString(),
      userName:userName.toString(),
      userEmailAddress:userEmailAddress.toString(),
    );
  }

  Future<bool> remove()async{

    final SharedPreferences sp = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    sp.remove('token');
    return true;

  }
}
```

and this is how i'm saving data which I get from Login API response and using this code on Login screen

```
final userPreference =Provider.of<UserViewModel>(context, listen: false);
userPreference.saveUser(UserModel(userId: value['data']['id'].toString()));
```

and this is how I'm getting data from sharedPrefernce, using this code of `Drawer Widget` class

```
Future<UserModel> getUserDate() => UserViewModel().getUser();
    getUserDate().then((value)async{
      setState(() {
      GlobalVariables.token=value.token.toString();
      });
   });
```

**PROBLEM**

The problem is I need to save the `stripe_id` on sharedpreference so when user get logged in there is screen called Add Card when user click on button an API hits and on its response I'm getting `stripe_id` and saving it to `sharedpereference` same as i saved login response,  data. But when I came back to `Drawer Widget` class it prints null value of `token`. It works fine when I'm not saving `stripe_id` on `sharedpreference`.

here is the code how I'm saving `stripe_id`

```
final userPreference =Provider.of<UserViewModel>(context,listen: false);
userPreference.saveUser(UserModel(stripe_id: createCard['id'].toString()));
```

But, when i do above code like this

```
final userPreference =Provider.of<UserViewModel>(context,listen: false);
userPreference.saveUser(UserModel(stripe_id: createCard['id'].toString()));
userPreference.saveUser(UserModel(token: "22424"));
```

I get the `token` value `"22424"`,but I don't want to do it like this. My point is when the sharepreference data is null after saving other data on other key.

Kindly help where I'm doing wrong.

Comment: you're simply overriding with null values everytime you're calling ``userPreference.saveUser()``

Comment: You're passing User object with selected values like stripe_id or token or user_id and and keeping other values null and then when you call saveUser method, you're saving only the passed values while saving others NULL.

Comment: so you mean everytime when i need to save other values first i need to get it them storing on other variable and then saving them again?

Comment: You should check for NULL values for each values and save only when value is not null for each properties.

Comment: how to do this, can you post some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're simply overriding with `NULL` values every time you're calling the `saveUser()` method with an `User` object with `NULL` values for it's properties.

You're passing an `User` object with selected values like `stripe_id` or `token` while passing other values `NULL` and then when you call the `saveUser()` method, you're saving only the passed values while saving others as NULL by default which get's saved too.

You should check for NULL value before saving each objet's property.

---

Update your **saveUser** method with this:

```
Future<bool> saveUser(UserModel user) async {
  final SharedPreferences sp = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  if (user.token != null) sp.setString('token', user.token.toString());
  if (user.userId != null) sp.setString('user_id', user.userId.toString());
  if (user.stripeId != null) sp.setString('stripe_id', user.stripeId.toString());
  if (user.userName != null) sp.setString('userName', user.userName.toString());
  if (user.userEmailAddress != null) sp.setString('userEmailAddress', user.userEmailAddress.toString());

  notifyListeners();
  return true;
}
```